# Multiple (properly aligned) sidebars in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have written two `sidebarLayout` functions, with `position="left"` as parameter for one and `position="right"` for the other. The second `sidebar` appears on the right side, but below the first `sidebar` as shown in the figure below.

[image]

How to display the second sidebar at the same vertical level as first sidebar?

Comment: why not use fluidRow and column? 

http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson3/

Comment: The purpose of this application is to compare two different datasets x and y. x and y have their own filters in sidebars 1 and 2. I might be wrong, but fluidRow doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: U need a little knowledge of CSS to tweak this. The sidebars in shiny are divs in a fluid container and by default the divs in a fluid container are separated by a new line character. I guess, you can change that by writing your own CSS file with `.row {display:inline-block;}` (the `display` element is `block `by default)

Comment: @Shiva thanks. I'll give it a shot.